# Submit iOS app to apple store that interact with third party hardware over wifi

Tags: iphone, ios, iostream, app-store

I would like to know what all possibilities are there to submit an iOS app that interact with third party hardware over wifi.

1. Do I need to go for MiFi certification for the hardware?
2. I have seen STB (Set Top Bbox) application which does similar things and STB are not Mifi certified
3. If apple allows such application then Do I need to send my hardware to apple while submitting application?

Regards,

Comment: Good question, but StackOverflow is not a site for legal matters. Voted to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You don't need certification. You only need certification when your device communicates via bluetooth or the 30-pin connector.
2. Exactly.
3. No, you don't need to send your hardware. You do, however, need to make sure your code properly handles the case when your hardware isn't available. You should also provide detailed notes to the reviewers explaining what your hardware does etc.

Edit (see comments): In some cases Apple has requested access to hardware in order to review apps.

Comment: Are we sure about item 3? I'm surprised Apple does not want to test the entire App with the third party device.

Comment: Usually they'll just ask you to send them a video unless they're wary of what you're doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, Apple asks us to send hardware to them or they wouldn't review our app.

Comment: We just had to send some hardware to Apple in order for them to even look at our app.

Answer (score 0):

a far as i know, only bluethooth hardware need to be apple certified, not wifi hardware...